# Linux Intel 64bit Assembly Division

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, intel, division

I am battling to understand why my division is not working, below is my current code, which simply takes in two single digits and attempts to divide them:

```
STDIN equ 0
SYS_READ equ 0

STDOUT equ 1
SYS_WRITE equ 1

segment .data
    num1 dq 0
    num2 dq 0
    quot dq 0
    rem dq 0

segment .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov rax, SYS_READ
    mov rdi, STDIN
    mov rsi, num1
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall

    mov rax, SYS_READ
    mov rdi, STDIN
    mov rsi, num2
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall

    mov rax, [num1]
    sub rax, '0'

    mov rbx, [num2]
    sub rbx, '0'

    xor rdx, rdx
    div rbx

    add rax, '0'

    mov [quot], rax
    mov [rem], rdx

    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, quot
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

Now as far as I understand when dividing the assembler will divide RDX:RAX by the operand RBX. I can only assume this is where the problem is coming in, the fact that I am dividing a 128bit value by a 64bit value. Whenever I enter something such as 8 / 2 or something similar, I receive the value 1 as the quotient. What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As usual, learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read 2 bytes for the operands, but it seems you ignore the 2nd, when you shouldn't.
Assuming you type 8 and 2 and one line each, you will read "8\n" and "2\n". You then subtract '0', but you leave the '\n', so your operands will be `0x08 0x0A` and `0x02 0x0A`, which are 2568 and 2562. And 2568 / 2562 = 1.

Comment: A possible solution is to use `movzx rax, byte [num1]` and similarly for `num2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my issue. I always wondered what happened to that extra new line. Whenever I used add or sub it worked fine so I (wrongly) assumed it just dissapeared. Thanks to @Jester as well for the solution and yeah I am busy learning how to use GDB at the moment.