# Basic assembly calculator assignment not working

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

We need to do addition, subtraction, multiplication and division with single digits that are entered in using syscalls. For some reason my addition is the only thing that works. I cannot figure out why the rest don't work. All of them outputs nothing, except for multiplication that works if you multiply by 1.

My subtract code:

```
segment .data
    one db 0
    two db 0
    diff db 0

segment .text
global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    lea rsi, [one]
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall
    mov rbx, [one]
    sub rbx, 48
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    lea rsi, [two]
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall
    sub rbx, [two]
    mov [diff], rbx
    ;xor rbx, rbx
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rdx, 1
    lea rsi, [diff]
    syscall
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

My multiplication code:

```
segment .data
one db 0
two db 0
multi db 0

segment .text
global _start

_start:
mov eax, 0
mov edi, 0
lea esi, [one]
mov edx, 2
syscall
;mov ebx, [one]
;sub ebx, '0'
mov eax, 0
mov edi, 0
lea rsi, [two]
mov edx, 2
syscall
mov eax, [one]
sub eax, '0'
;mov ecx, [two]
;sub ecx, '0'
mul dword [two]
mov [multi], eax 
xor edx, edx
mov eax, 1
mov edi, 1
mov edx, 1
lea esi, [multi]
syscall
mov eax, 60
xor edi, edi
syscall
```

And division code:

```
segment .data
one db 0
two db 0
qout db 0

segment .text
global _start

_start:
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, 0
lea rsi, [one]
mov rdx, 2
syscall
;mov rbx, [one]
;sub rbx, '0'
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, 0
lea rsi, [two]
mov edx, 2
syscall
mov eax, [one]
sub eax, '0'
mov edx, 0
mov ecx, two
;sub ecx, '0'
div ecx
mov [qout], [rax]
;xor rdx, rdx
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rdx, 1
lea rsi, [qout]
syscall
mov rax, 60
xor rdi, rdi
syscall
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not working.

This is my addition for reference:

```
segment .data
one db 0
two db 0
sum db 0

segment .text
global _start

_start:
mov eax, 0 ;read
mov edi, 0 ;file descriptor
lea esi, [one] ;write to one
mov edx, 2 ;size of input in bytes
syscall
mov ebx, [one]
sub ebx, '0' ;'convert' to int
mov eax, 0 ;again another input
mov edi, 0
lea rsi, [two]
mov edx, 2
syscall
add ebx, [two] ;add two to one
mov [sum], ebx ;move sum into [sum]
xor ebx, ebx ;clear the register
mov eax, 1 ;syscall write
mov edi, 1 ;file descriptor
mov edx, 1 ;output one byte
lea esi, [sum] ;output sum
syscall
mov eax, 60 ;syscall 60 is exit
xor edi, edi ;exit(0)
syscall
```

Comment: Posting your addition code might help too.

Comment: Comment your code if you want others to help, and learn to use a debugger so you can step through your code and fix your own mistakes. From a first glance, this has at least the same problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139441/linux-intel-64bit-assembly-division/32140194).

Comment: I will try the solution there, I have added my addition now with comments

Comment: `mov eax, [one] / mul dword [two]` <-- `one` and `two` are clearly not `DWORDs` since you declared them using `db 0`.

Comment: Oh, do I use byte for db then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In my code I subtracted '0' from both numbers and after the operation I just added '0' again.For Division I did what the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139441/linux-intel-64bit-assembly-division/32140194) suggested.